# Date from to filter Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have table of dates from json and i need to make 2 inputs which will filtring this dates from to. Ex. after entering in first input 1990, and in second input 2016 in my table will be only dates from 1990 to 2016.
How could it look like from the code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the you have added in your code? add it ? before asking suggesting you to see this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have an Array called datesArray with dates.

```
<div>
    <input ng-model="dateFilter.from" class="form-control" />
    <input ng-model="dateFilter.to" class="form-control" />

    <div ng-repeat="date in datesArray | filterBy:dateFilterFunction">
        {{date}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.dateFilter={};
$scope.dateFilterFunction= function(date){
    return (date>$scope.dateFilter.from && date<$scope.dateFilter.to)
}
```

Comment: I guess your HTML capitalization is wrong, you would replace the dateFilter function. I guess the models should be datefilter.from and datefilter.to, all lower cases.